# iOS: Creating Directories in APP/Library/Caches/

Tags: ios, directory

Does anyone know if it's possible to create directories in {APP}/Library/Caches/ and successfully read data from it?

I am able to create a dir:
{APP}/Library/Caches/tmp/

I download a few files in the tmp folder. Then move them to:
{APP}/Library/Caches/

I use NSFileManager.moveItemAtPath: but after they've been moved to the final destination they aren't readable. I use [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:] but it comes back NULL.

What's strange is that I see TestFlightApp storing content in {APP}/Library/Caches/TestFlight. But how does anyone read content in a custom directory?

Am I missing something when I create the directory or move the file?

Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind. The problem is I was mixing in C source code. Make sure you always use NSFileManager and NSFileHandle. Any C libs mixed in are probably diverting iOS caching mechanisms which breaks it.